# Function "sizeof" returning incorrect value for a struct pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc

I'm trying to get the size of a variable named *a which points to where an instance of a struct named "aluno" is stored, but it is returning me the incorrect size (36, which should be actually 33 bytes). Also, I'm trying to return each of the struct's elements' addresses in memory, but the program is throwing me an error, for example: "request for member 'ra' in something not a structure or union".

The goal is for me to show on the screen the full size of `*a`, as well as the address of `a` itself. I also need to show the value, address, and size of every member of the `*a` struct (such as ra, nome, etc.)

Can anyone help me?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

typedef struct {
    int ra;
    char nome[20];
    int idade;
    char sexo;
    float media;    
} aluno;

int main() {
    aluno *a;
    aluno aux;

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

    a = (aluno*) malloc(sizeof(aluno));

    printf("RA: "); scanf("%d", &aux.ra);
    printf("Nome: "); scanf("%s", &aux.nome);
    printf("Idade: "); scanf("%d", &aux.idade); fflush(stdin);
    printf("Sexo: "); scanf("%c", &aux.sexo);
    printf("Média: "); scanf("%f", &aux.media);

    *a = aux;

    printf("\nEndereço de memória do ponteiro a: %p\n", a);
    printf("Tamanho de *a: %d\n\n", sizeof(*a));

    printf("   Valor de a.ra: %d\n", (*a).ra);
    printf("Endereço de a.ra: %p\n", a.ra);
    printf(" Tamanho de a.ra: %d\n\n", sizeof((*a).ra));

    printf("   Valor de a.nome: %s\n", (*a).nome);
    printf("Endereço de a.nome: %p\n", a.nome);
    printf(" Tamanho de a.nome: %d\n\n", sizeof((*a).nome));

    printf("   Valor de a.idade: %d\n", (*a).idade);
    printf("Endereço de a.idade: %p\n", a.idade);
    printf(" Tamanho de a.idade: %d\n\n", sizeof((*a).idade));

    printf("   Valor de a.sexo: %c\n", (*a).sexo);
    printf("Endereço de a.sexo: %p\n", a.sexo);
    printf(" Tamanho de a.sexo: %d\n\n", sizeof((*a).sexo));

    printf("   Valor de a.media: %.1f\n", (*a).media);
    printf("Endereço de a.media: %p\n", a.media);
    printf(" Tamanho de a.media: %d\n", sizeof((*a).media));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't get the error you're talking about, but I get [numerous others](https://pastebin.com/UDrm6tkZ). The error messages I get are quite clear and tell you exactly how to fix each problem (except the first one, which is fixed by replacing `&aux.nome` with `aux.nome`)

Comment: Tip: `(*p).field` can be written as `p->field`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, `sizeof` is not a function; it is evaluated at compile time and it cannot be wrong.

Secondly, you seem to be unaware that there can be padding between struct members to ensure they are naturally aligned.

Assuming `sizeof(int) == 4` and `sizeof(float) == 4`:

```c
typedef struct {
    int ra;         // offset=0,  size=4
    char nome[20];  // offset=4,  size=20
    int idade;      // offset=24, size=4
    char sexo;      // offset=28, size=1
      // (padding)     offset=29, size=3
    float media;    // offset=32, size=4
} aluno;            // total size=36
```

Comment: You make it sound like that is what you'll get on an x86, but it's up to the compiler, isn't it? And don't some compilers provide ways of controlling the layout?

Comment: That was clarifying. But unfortunately, I'll have to ask another question, since this one was wrongfully closed without my second issue being answered (the one regarding the error).

Comment: `sizeof` is not evaluated at compile time for variable length arrays.

Comment: @Eric Yes that is a good corner case.